# How to disable sIFR for headings in a specific div

Tags: sifr

Is it possible to have sIFR 2 replace headings in a content like #content, but not in #sidebar?

Thanks,

osu

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a more specific selector in your replace statement.

Instead of something like this:

```
if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
    sIFR.replaceElement("h1", named({sFlashSrc: "./vandenkeere.swf", sColor: "#000", sCase: "upper"}));
};
```

You need a more specific selector:

```
if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
    sIFR.replaceElement("#content h1", named({sFlashSrc: "./vandenkeere.swf", sColor: "#000", sCase: "upper"}));
};
```

Comment: Hi, just responded to your answer as another question because the code wasn't displaying correctly using just the comment box

Comment: I can't comment on your answer, but you said "maybe this is a CSS issue" and I would agree with that. You have to update your sifr-screen.css as well as the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting back to me.

I'm using this code, but the h2 tags etc. are still affected in the #sidebar div because I can't see them (although there's no flash animation there, so maybe this is a css issue?):

```
if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
sIFR.replaceElement(named({
    sSelector:"#content h1,#content h2,#content h3,#content h4,#content h5,#content h6",
    sFlashSrc:"/wp-content/themes/name/sifr/fssophie.swf",
    sColor:"#dd2527",
    sLinkColor:"#dd2527",
    sBgColor:"#ffffff",
    sHoverColor:"#ed292b",
    nPaddingTop:0,
    nPaddingBottom:0,
    sFlashVars:"textalign=left&offsetTop=0"}));};
```

Comment: sIFR 2 has some default CSS rules that hide a few extra elements, these are probably interfering.

But why not use sIFR 3?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I had the same problem as you. Go into the sIFR-screen.css, and you'll see:

```
.sIFR-hasFlash h4 {
    visibility: hidden;
    letter-spacing: -5px;
    font-size: 21px;
}
```

This means that all h4's will be hidden if the computer has flash - disable it, and provide more specific CSS if you like...

origninal problem...
You put sIFR on the page, all the Headers disapear... you enable some specific #ids .. great, but the rest are still dead... until you tweak sIFRs css...